# PACF for MA(1) process

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima

I have MA(1) process:

$X_t=\epsilon_t+\theta\epsilon_{t-1}$

I want to prove the equation for PACF for $n\geq2$

$\alpha(n)=\phi_{nn} = \frac{\theta^n(-1)^{n+1}}{1+\theta^2+...+\theta^{2n}}$

I found the tip that if I show this for any $j \in \{1, ...,n-1\}$

$\phi_{n,n-j}=(-\theta)^{-j}(1+\theta^2+...+\theta^{2j})\phi_{nn}$

the result I want to obtain will be obvious. I did prove the equation above but I don't get that it implies the equation for $\alpha(n)$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this from a course or a textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read it' [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: This is a book Introduction to Time Seres and Forecasting - Davis, Brockwell, problem 3.12 (page 110)

Comment: Are you mixing up notation? What is $k$?

Answer (score 3):

In another edition of Brockwell and Davis this problem is 3.20. The calculation of $\phi_{nn}$ relies on solving the system

$$\Gamma_n(\phi_{11},...,\phi_{nn})'=(\gamma(1),...,\gamma(n))',$$
where  $\Gamma_n$ is the covariance matrix of the vector $(X_1,...,X_n)$, and $\gamma(i)=cov(X_{t},X_{t+i})$.

Now for MA(1) process the matrix $\Gamma_n$ is tridiagonal, and the $\gamma(j)=0$ for $j>1$. So you have the resursive system, from which you can calculate the $\phi_{nn}$.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly how you wrote. I did it. I calculated recursively $\phi_{n, n-1}, \phi_{n, n-2}, ... \phi_{n,1}$ from this system. And I got the equation you can see in my post (last one). But I can't find $\phi_{nn}$

Comment: Use the first equation: $(1+\theta^2)\phi_{n,1}+\theta\phi_{n,2}=\theta$. If you have the recursive formula, for all terms expressed in $\phi_{n,n}$ then putting in this equation you can solve for $\phi_{n,n}$.

Comment: @mpiktas: $\gamma(j)=0$ for $j>1$

Comment: Yes, but $\gamma(1)$ is not zero.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. You write "$\gamma(j)=0$ for $j>0$", but that is not true for $j=1$.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it via the Durbin-Levinson recursion on page 70. In general,

$$ \phi_{nn} = \left[\gamma(n)-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\phi_{n-1,j}\gamma(n-j)\right]v_{n-1}^{-1},$$

where the $\gamma$ are the autocovariances, $v_{n}=v_{n-1}[1-\phi_{nn}^2]$ and $v_0=\gamma(0)$. Now, since $\gamma(n)=0$ for $n>1$ in the case of an $MA(1)$ process the expression simplifies to

$$ \phi_{nn} = -\phi_{n-1,n-1}\gamma(1)v_{n-1}^{-1}$$

for our purposes. Say,

$$ \phi_{22} = -\phi_{11}\gamma(1)v_{1}^{-1} = -\frac{\phi_{11}\gamma(1)}{\gamma(0)[1-\phi_{11}^2]}=-\frac{\phi_{11}\rho(1)}{1-\phi_{11}^2}=-\frac{\rho(1)^2}{1-\rho(1)^2},$$

where I used $\rho(1)=\phi_{11}$. Plugging in, using $\rho(1)=\theta/(1+\theta^2)$, gives me the right result.

In general, I get

$$ \phi_{nn} = -\frac{\phi_{n-1,n-1}\rho(1)}{\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(1-\phi_{jj}^2)},$$

but I do not see how to verify the general result from there.

EDIT: I thought a general solution to this equation would maybe be known and posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176496/solution-to-a-specific-differential-equation). In the answer, you can read about the completion of this alternative derivation.

Answer (score 0):

From Time Series Analysis, 1990 by William W. S. Wei book

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \phi_{kk}  = 
  \frac{ \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & \rho_1 & \rho_2 & \cdots & \rho_{{k}-2} & \rho_{1}  \\
      \rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1 & \cdots & \rho_{{k}-3} & \rho_{2}  \\
      \vdots &  & & \cdots &  & \vdots \\
      \vdots &  &  & \cdots &  & \vdots \\
      \rho_{{k}-2} & \rho_{{k}-3} & \rho_{{k}-4} & \cdots & 
      1 & \rho_{k-1} \\
      \rho_{{k}-1} & \rho_{{k}-2} & \rho_{{k}-3} & \cdots & 
      \rho_1 & \rho_k \\
    \end{pmatrix}
  }
  {
    \det 
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & \rho_1 & \rho_2 & \cdots & \rho_{{k}-2} & \rho_{{k}-1}  \\
      \rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1 & \cdots & \rho_{{k}-3} & \rho_{{k}-2}  \\
      \vdots &  &  & \cdots &  & \vdots \\
      \vdots &  &  & \cdots &  & \vdots \\
      \rho_{{k}-2} & \rho_{{k}-3} & \rho_{{k}-4} & \cdots & 
      1 & \rho_1 \\
      \rho_{{k}-1} & \rho_{{k}-2} & \rho_{{k}-3} & \cdots & 
      \rho_1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \, .
  }
\end{eqnarray*}

We know that $\phi_{00}=1$ and $\phi_{11}=\rho_1$. For $k>1$,
For an MA(1) process we found that $\rho_i=0$ for $i\ge 2$. Then we should evaluate
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \phi_{kk}  = 
  \frac{ \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & \rho_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & \rho_{1}  \\
      \rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1 & \ddots &  &  & \vdots & 0  \\
      0  & \rho_1 & 1 &  \rho_1 & \ddots &  & \vdots & \vdots  \\
      \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
      \vdots &  &  \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots \\
      \vdots &  &  &  \ddots & \rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1 & \vdots  \\
      \vdots & & & & \ddots & \rho_1 & 1 & \vdots  \\
      0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0  &  \rho_1  & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}
  }
  {
    \det 
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & \rho_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\
      \rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1 & \ddots & & &  & \vdots \\
      0  & \rho_1 & 1 &  \rho_1 & \ddots & &  & \vdots \\
      \vdots & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & &  \vdots \\
      \vdots &  & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
      \vdots &  &  &  \ddots & \rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1 & 0  \\
      \vdots &  & & &  \ddots & \rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1  \\
      0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0  & \rho_1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
  }
\end{eqnarray*}

where each matrix has $k$ rows and columns.  We need to evaluate these determinants.
For the numerator, we expand the determinant using the last column.
Then After eliminating the first row and last column we end up with a upper triangular matrix with $\rho_1$ in the diagonal. Then the numerator has the value of $\rho_1^k$.

For the denominator we solve a more general problem.
\begin{eqnarray*}
  A_k = \det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    c & a & b & 0 &  \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & c & a & b  &  \cdots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots   & \cdots &  \vdots  \\
    0 & 0 &  & \vdots & c & a
  \end{pmatrix} .
\end{eqnarray*}
where $n$ is the number of rows and columns
We expand by the first row and find
\begin{eqnarray}
  A_k = a A_{k-1} - b ( c A_{k-2})
  \label{solsAk}
\end{eqnarray}
This is a homogeneous difference equation with initial conditions:
$A_1=a$, $A_2=a^2 - bc$. The characteristic polynomial is
\begin{eqnarray*}
  P(\lambda) = 1 - a \lambda + b c \lambda^2 ,
\end{eqnarray*}
with roots
\begin{eqnarray*}
  r_{1,2} = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4 bc}}{2bc}
\end{eqnarray*}
We follow the method to solve linear difference equations

Since $a=1, b=c=\rho_1$ we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
  r_{1,2} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - \rho_1^2}}{2 \rho_1^2} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Then, the roots are different and real (since $0 < \rho_1 < 1$), so the solution is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
  A_k = C_1 r_1^k + C_2 r_2^k \quad , \quad (1)
\end{eqnarray*}
with $C_1, C_2$ to be found using the initial conditions. Let us reduce the initial conditions
to simple expressions. If we assume $A_0=1$, then $A_1=a$ and $A_2=a A_1 - bc A_0 = a^2 -bc$
which matches the second order solution for $k=2$. Then we use the initial
conditions as
\begin{eqnarray*}
  A_0=1 \quad , \quad A_1 = a.
\end{eqnarray*}

The solution, for in terms of $\rho_1$ is not obvious except for the first coefficients
For example, clearly $A_1 = a =1$, $A_2=a^2-bc = 1- \rho_1^2$ and
$A_3 = a A_2 - bc A_1 = 1-\rho_1^2 - \rho^2 = 1 - 2 \rho_1^2$.
Now ,from the equation for $\rho_1$ in an MA process,  $\rho_1=\beta_1/(1 + \beta_1^2)$ and
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \phi_{11} = \rho_1 = \frac{\beta_1}{1 + \beta_1^2} 
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \phi_{22} &=& \frac{\rho_1^2}{1 - \rho_1^2} \\
  &=& \frac{\beta_1^2}{(1 + \beta_1^2)^2 \left (1 - \frac{\beta_1^2}{1 + \beta_1^2} \right )}  \\
  &=& \frac{\beta_1^2}{(1 + \beta_1^2)^2 - \beta_1^2} \\
  &=& \frac{\beta_1^2}{1 + 2 \beta_1^2 + \beta_1^4 - \beta_1^2} \\
  &=& \frac{\beta_1^2}{1 + \beta_1^2 + \beta_1^4}
 \end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \phi_{33} &=& \frac{\rho_1^3}{1 - 2 \rho_1^2} \\
  &=& \frac{\beta_1^3}{(1 + \beta_1^2)^3 \left ( 1 - 2 \frac{\beta_1^2}{( 1 + \beta_1^2)^2} \right )} \\
  &=& \frac{\beta_1^3}{(1 + \beta_1^2)^3 - 2 \beta_1^2 (1 + \beta_1^2)} \\
  &=& \frac{\beta_1^3}{1 + 3 \beta_1^2 + 3 \beta_1^4 + \beta_1^6 - 2 \beta_1^2 - 2 \beta_1^4} \\
  &=& \frac{\beta_1^3}{1 + \beta_1^2 + \beta_1^4 + \beta_1^6 }
\end{eqnarray*}
There is a clear pattern that indicates
\begin{eqnarray}
  \phi_{kk} = \frac{\beta_1^k}{\sum_{i=0}^k \beta_1^{2i}}.
  \label{pktoappd}
\end{eqnarray}

This pattern can be easily shown by induction and the recursion (1) above